# Make textview take up half of the width of the screen with relativelayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

I have a `TextView` that I want to have 1/8 of the whole screen, and dp just works to get half of the height but how do I get the 4 `TextView`'s to each share the bottom half of the screen equally?
Right now they share the height equally, but the ones on the left are wider than the ones on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of your `RelativeLayout` you need to make a horizontal `LinearLayout` just for these `TextView`'s.  Then to make them all take up an equal amount of space, assign an equal weight to them all with `weight="1"`.

If you want a `TextView` to take up more or less space than the others, just assign a proportionate weight to it.  For example if you have 4 views and want the first one to take up 1/2 of the space and the other 3 to share the rest equally, set the weight of the first view to 3 and the others to 1.

Answer (score -1):

You can't with a relative layout-  consider a PercentRelativeLayout